# How to instantiate loggers inside static methods in Log4j (For a large project)?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I know the question title is a bit raw, the more I tried to make it clear in a single statement the less I was successful.
Anyways, in a web application project I need to log every action (and the errors which occur inside them) with Log4j, there are hundreds of classes in the project and I want to avoid having a Logger object for each class. The level needed for logging is ERROR.
So, I've thought of a custom class containing a static method which handles the Logger object's "error()" method. As shown below:

```
public class LoggerUtil {

    public static void error(String message, Object classObject) {
        String className = classObject.getClass().getName();
        Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(className);
        logger.error(message);
    }
}
```

So that whenever "LoggerUtil.error(message, this.getClass().getName())" is called anywhere in the project, we are able to log something by current class' related logger.
Problem is that this doesn't seem to work, I guess it is not possible to instantiate a logger related to a specific class in another class.
When our LoggerUtil.error() is called in one class the ERROR log that is given shows an unrelated class as it's source (java.lang.String). I wonder if there's a way to make this idea work?

[UPDATE]: Problem solved. There was a problem in design, which was fixed in this way:

```
public class LoggerUtil {

    public static void error(String message, String className) {
        Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(className);
        logger.error(message);
    }
}
```

The second argument was changed into String so the class name is passed to the method directly. The logger works fine now.

Comment: How do you call this method from another class? How do you diagnose that the class is incorrect? Why use getClass().getName() instead of simply getClass(), since LogManager has a getLogger(Class) method? Why not create a static logger in each class and reuse it, instead of constantly asking the logger to the LogManager?

Comment: Let's say we have another class called "CustomClass" and it has an execute() method. Inside execute() we'll call LoggerUtil.error("Error", this.getClass().getName()); what I expect is to have a log with level ERROR and it's source class as CustomClass, but it's not like this, java.lang.String will be shown as source of the error. And the last question, what's the difference? Should it not get the same class in both situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method expects an object as argument, and gets the class of this object to get the appropriate logger.

But when you call your method, you call it with

```
LoggerUtil.error("Error", this.getClass().getName());
```

So, what you pass as argument is not the object for which to log (i.e. the CustomClass instance), but the name of its class (`"com.foo.CustomClass"`), which is a String. And in the method, you just ask a logger for the name of the class of the object `"com.foo.CustomClass"`, which is thus java.lang.String.

In short you're getting the name of the class oof the object twice: once in the caller, and once in the called method.

So, change your call to

```
LoggerUtil.error("Error", this);
```

and you'll get the desired result.

Comment: You are right, when you commented about the method's arguments I took another look at the code and got it figured therefore. But thanks for the answer again.